# Python OpenCV video resolution

Tags: python, opencv, video, resolution

I try to change video resolution (with mp4!) (to 800x600) in this way : but its doesn't work, when I use cap.get(3) and (4), its return every time defualt 1280x720!

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('file')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    cv2.waitKey(10)

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cap.set(3, 800)
    cap.set(4, 600)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA) 
    print cap.get(3) # return default 1280       

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I tried -

```
cv2.resizeWindow("ssss", 300, 300),
```

and

```
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800)
```

no effect !

Comment: try with your webcam by cv2.VideoCapture(0) it give you 800 not 1280

Comment: With webcam its work, change to file ! - mp4

Comment: @TheRutubeify If you find the answer on Stack OverFlow. You should follow these rules. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. If you know the answer to the question. You should give the answer in Answer panel. Don't give the answer in question panel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(cap.isOpened()):
    cv2.waitKey(10)

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cap.set(3, 800)
    cap.set(4, 600)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA) 
    print cap.get(3) # return default 1280       

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This your code works with webcame, not with file

for a video file, you can **resize the window**

```
cv2.resizeWindow(winname, width, height)
```

for that first define window with name and resize it

**example**

```
  cv2.namedWindow("frame", 0);
  cv2.resizeWindow("frame", 800,600);
```

[for Detail resize window](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#resizewindow)

Comment: How to use it ? cv2.resizeWindow("cap", 300, 300) in loop ? I tried this way, no change (

Comment: Its just open new "blank" empty window with head "Final"

Comment: @TheRutubeify cv2.imshow('frame',gray) line change to cv2.imshow('Final',gray)

Comment: Yes its helpful, because I can't find in docs and internet any solution about this simple feature !

Comment: @TheRutubeify accept the answer so for another user also can get right answer

Comment: This solution has saved me!!

Answer (score 3):

I think there are a few things in your code that might need attention.

1. As described in the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) for `VideoCapture`, if you want to access your default WebCam, you'd need to initialise the class as follows:

   ```
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture('file')
   ```

   If you are trying to then change the resolution of the camera, I'd suggest to move the two `set` lines right below the initialisation of `cap` and only perform it once - not each time you read in the frame. You can also use constants to access the right attributes:

   ```
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture('file')
   cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
   cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

   # Your while loop and the rest of the code...
   ```
2. If you are trying to read the frame from a file and want to change it's resolution, you'd probably want to use the `resize` method as described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize). This would need to be done inside the loop, right after you read in the frame. It could be something like:

   ```
   resize(ret, ret, Size(800, 600), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
   ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800)   cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600) Its does't help !

Comment: Its the same - cap.set(3, 800)  and  cap.set(4, 600) like I wrote above!

Answer (score 1):

`cap.set()` has no effect below resolutions of `640,480`
(at least for my macbook pro)
You can increase the resolution, but for example setting it to `300,300` has no effect.
As for my experience you ned to call `resize()` on the frame after you `read()` it.

Comment: Same for me on macbook pro High Sierra. Always printing `width 640` no matter what I put lower than 640.